# javascript to loop through table rows with a classname

Tags: javascript, arrays

Here is the following table code and I want to store all TD values into an Array.

```
<tr class="item-row">
    <td class="item-name"><textarea>Item</textarea></td>
    <td class="description"><textarea>Item</textarea></td>
    <td><textarea class="cost">$0.00</textarea></td>
    <td><textarea class="qty">0</textarea></td>
    <td><span class="price">$0.00</span></td>
</tr>

<tr class="item-row">
    <td class="item-name"><textarea>Item</textarea></td>
    <td class="description"><textarea>Item</textarea></td>
    <td><textarea class="cost">$0.00</textarea></td>
    <td><textarea class="qty">0</textarea></td>
    <td><span class="price">$0.00</span></td>
</tr>
```

For this I have written this following code:

```
function checkForm() {
    var table = document.getElementsByClassName("item-row");
    var arr = new Array();
    for (var i = 0, row; row = table.rows[i]; i++) {
        for (var j = 0, col; col = row.cells[j]; j++) {
            arr.push(row.cells[j].val);
        }  
    }
}
```

But this gives me no output...I am new to javascript so may be am missing something in big time.

Comment: Have you done any debugging? Try checking the values before you add them and you should be able to narrow it down. Is table being defined properly? Does row.cells[j].val have a value.

Comment: Notice that `table` is not a *table*, but a `<tr>`.

Comment: @JCOC611 yes...so for <tr> how should I use the loop?

Comment: @LachlanGoodhew-Cook I just want to loop through the <tr> with classname "item-row"...may be on this point am missing something

Comment: I know what you want to do I'm just trying to give you some advice to help YOU figure out what's wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have is a good first effort for being new to JavaScript, but, yes, there are quite a few items that need updating.   :)

Here is what you would need to do what you are trying to do:

```
function checkForm() {
    var rows = document.getElementsByClassName("item-row");
    var arr = new Array();

    for (i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
        var cols = rows[i].getElementsByTagName("td");

        for (j = 0; j < cols.length; j++) {
            arr.push(cols[j].textContent);
        }
    }
}
```

1. You need to cycle through each row . . . the easiest way to do this by going from `i = 0` to `i < rows.length` in your for loop.
2. Once you have a row, you need to gather all of the columns in the row, by finding all of the `<td>` elements (`var cols = rows[i].getElementsByTagName("td");`);
3. Then, you loop through each of those, just like you did with the rows (`j = 0` to `j < cols.length`
4. Finally, to get the text contained in each `td`, you use the `textContent` property . . . values (i.e., the `value` property) are used only for `<input>` elements

There were a couple of syntax errors in there, too (you used `,` instead of `;`, when building your `for` loop and you used `val` instead of `value`, when attempting to get the `td` content), but that was all that I saw.

**Edit:** I'm also assuming that you just did not paste your `<table>` tags in when you added your HTML, but, if you didn't your `<tr>` tags must be inside a `<table`.

**Edit 2:**  My solution also skips the looking at the tags inside the `<td>` elements, since they are not standard (4 contain `<textarea>` inputs and the 5th a `<span>`).  If you want to go down one more level of detail, you could use `.value` on the textareas and (again) `.textContent` on the `<span>`.  By using `.textContent` one level up, you are ignoring all HTML tags insid the `<td>` tags and returning only the text.

Comment: @talemyn...I have used your code with a alert but it shows up nothing...the code is  function checkForm() {
    var rows = document.getElementsByClassName("item-row");
    var arr = new Array();

    for (i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
        var cols = rows[i].getElementsByTagName("td");

        for (j = 0; j < cols.length; j++) {
            arr.push(cols[j].textContent);
            alert(cols[j].textContent);
        }
    }
}

Comment: Are you returning anything?   If you want to see it in an alert, then you would need to add `return arr;` right before the last `}` and then you could run `alert(checkForm());` and the result would show.  Alternately, you could add `alert(arr);` at that same point in the code and it would show then.

Answer (score 4):

Your code is almost right, the thing is that `rows` property work for tables not for `tr`s so you have to take a table instead of the `tr` directly.

The other thing is that `getElementsByClassName` returns an array of your elements so you have to use `[index]` to get your element.

The last thing is that to get the value for the `cell` you can't use `val`, so use `firstChild` to get the child and `value` to get the value as in the code, or better as @pawel suggest directly `cell.textarea` `:)`

Try with this code:

```js
function checkForm() {
    var table = document.getElementsByClassName("yourTable")[0];
    var arr = new Array();
    for (var i = 0, row; row = table.rows[i]; i++) {
        for (var j = 0, col; col = row.cells[j]; j++) {
            arr.push(row.cells[j].firstChild.value);
        }  
    }
    console.log(arr);
}
```

```html
<table class="yourTable">
<tr class="item-row">
              <td class="item-name"><textarea>Item</textarea></td>
              <td class="description"><textarea>Item</textarea></td>
              <td><textarea class="cost">$0.00</textarea></td>
              <td><textarea class="qty">0</textarea></td>
              <td><span class="price">$0.00</span></td>
          </tr>

          <tr class="item-row">
              <td class="item-name"><textarea>Item</textarea></td>
              <td class="description"><textarea>Item</textarea></td>
              <td><textarea class="cost">$0.00</textarea></td>
              <td><textarea class="qty">0</textarea></td>
              <td><span class="price">$0.00</span></td>
          </tr>
  </table>
<input type="button" onclick="checkForm();" value="check form"/>
```

Hope this helps,

Comment: Or `row.cells[j].textContent` to get both textarea values and text in spans.