# Javascript Exploring an Element's Children

Tags: javascript, html, dom

So lets say I have an element that contains this:

[image: Image Of Children]

How would I be able to run through all these children in javascript?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I iterate through an Elements child nodes using Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16672647/how-can-i-iterate-through-an-elements-child-nodes-using-javascript) OR [How to select all children of an element with javascript and change CSS property?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9780443/how-to-select-all-children-of-an-element-with-javascript-and-change-css-property)

Answer (score 0):

To iterate over tables seems not useful but here it is. Note I am using the class name for your tables above to find each one. If your example had different classes for each table this would not work.

```
var tables = document.getElementsByClassName("table");
var arr = new Array();

for (i = 0; i < tables .length; i++) {
    //do what you want here
}
```

If you want to work with the rows and cells within a table you might want to refer to this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28225614/javascript-to-loop-through-table-rows-with-a-classname).

Comment: I don't think you want to use `document`. OP is asking about a specific element

Answer (score 0):

Use querySelectorAll (which can be directly iterated over, unlike the HTMLCollection methods):

```
document.querySelectorAll('table.table').forEach(table => {
  // do something with each table
});
```